# How do you change the title or name of form1 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a quick question. how do I change the name of form1 in my app? whenever I try to use the properties to rename it the form becomes broken and i cant use it anymore. is there a way to change it during run-time or am i doing something wrong with the properties?
thanks.

Comment: Might want to clarify if you want to change either the title (.Text property) or the name (see my answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `Text` property of your form under the Properties panel, making sure that you've selected the form itself (and not some child control)

[image]

Comment: wow I can't believe it was that easy lol thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Funny, that the same answer I gave first :)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to change the text of the window during runtime, use the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property:

`this.Text = "Title";`

Comment: Note that this will not work if done before `InitializeComponent()`

Answer (score 1):

Use the Text property.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/SetCaptiontitleoftheform.htm

Comment: Not sure what happened with the first pasting, but it is fine now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of your form, select it in the solution explorer and press F2. Then type in the new name for that form (don't forget the '.cs'!) and when you press enter it'll ask you if you want Visual Studio to update all references to that form. Click Yes, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Form.Text property to get/set the title of the form either in design time or at runtime depending upon your requirement.
If you want to have a dynamic title that changes based on some events you can set it during the runtime for e.g. if you are showing the progress of a task in your form you will want to put the percentage completed in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just change the filename of the form to the one you want in design time.

Comment: You should not do it that way unless you have a trival name such as Form1.  If you require a title such as "User Entry Form", then making that the file name would be a bad idea.

Comment: @hivie7510 - agree, it was a simple question that skipped my attention.